# how to create a data model for the table in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, datatable, datamodel

the table is editable and it contain of => code/codename/price/kilograms

| code | codename | price | kilograms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

I tried to create a data model but it was hard to connect it to the table

Comment: give a try to Table or DataTable widget

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepOrange),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<MyModel> data = [
      MyModel(
        code: "code1",
        codeName: "codeName1",
        price: "price1",
        kilograms: "kilograms1",
      ),
      MyModel(
        code: "code2",
        codeName: "codeName2",
        price: "price2",
        kilograms: "kilograms2",
      ),
      MyModel(
        code: "code3",
        codeName: "codeName3",
        price: "price3",
        kilograms: "kilograms3",
      ),
      MyModel(
        code: "code4",
        codeName: "codeName4",
        price: "price4",
        kilograms: "kilograms4",
      )
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.black),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: DataTable(
                columnSpacing: 5,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                  width: 1,
                  color: Colors.black,
                )),
                columns: const <DataColumn>[
                  DataColumn(label: Text("code", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                  DataColumn(label: VerticalDivider()),
                  DataColumn(
                      label: Text("codename", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                  DataColumn(label: VerticalDivider()),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("price", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                  DataColumn(label: VerticalDivider()),
                  DataColumn(
                      label: Text("kilograms", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                ],
                rows: data
                    .map(
                      (i) => DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text(i.code)),
                        const DataCell(VerticalDivider()),
                        DataCell(Text(i.codeName)),
                        const DataCell(VerticalDivider()),
                        DataCell(Text(i.price)),
                        const DataCell(VerticalDivider()),
                        DataCell(Text(i.kilograms)),
                      ]),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyModel {
  String code;
  String codeName;
  String price;
  String kilograms;

  MyModel(
      {required this.code,
      required this.codeName,
      required this.price,
      required this.kilograms});
}
```

Here is a complete example of what you want to do

Answer (score 2):

As explained above, every object of MyModel class represents the row of table,
you just need to put all objects in the List which represents this entire table .

```
class MyModel {
  String code;
  String codeName;
  String price;
  String kilograms;

  MyModel(
      {required this.code,
      required this.codeName,
      required this.price,
      required this.kilograms});
}
```